# node js msssql connection error

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

I am trying to connect mssql server with node.js using mssql package. (https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql). And I am getting following error.
But my server name not xc-pc, my server name is xc-pc\r2.

is there any problem connect to msseql server named instance (r2)?
how can I fix this?

connection to xc-pc
2:1433 - failed Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to connect to named instance with this config:

```
var config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'xp-pc',
    database: '...',
    options: {
        instanceName: 'r2'
    }
}
```

You should also try to connect with IP address instead of hostname.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to connect to Azure instance. You will need to remove both tcp and the port from the server name as follow:

```
var config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'something.database.windows.net', // Remove tcp and port from the server name
    database: '...',

    options: {
         encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
    }
};
```

Comment: Great. Where to find info like this?